# Bash script produces empty file

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a script so I can search for 0kb files in a certain path, the output is to be redirected to a text file and then emailed. The script works except that the fie is empty either when it's emailed or when it's viewed after the script runs.

```
if [[ -n $(find /path/to/files/ -type f -empty -mmin +2) ]] then
> /tmp/output.txt ; mail -s "subject" -a /tmp/output.txt "email@address"
rm /tmp/ftr_output.txt
fi
```

Not sure if I missed something so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have explicitly instructed that `/tmp/output.txt` be __truncated__.  Why do you expect content to be in there?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm guessing `> /tmp/output.txt` was supposed to be inside the `$()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
# Save find results in a text file
find /path/to/files/ -type f -empty -mmin +2 > /tmp/output.txt

# Check that the text file isn't empty (meaning no results from find)
if [ -s /tmp/output.txt ]
then
    # Send the text file along with an email
    mail -s "subject" -a /tmp/output.txt "email@address"
fi
# Remove the text file
rm /tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: The test will always fail.  Try ` find ... > /tmp/output.txt; if [[ -n /tmp/output.txt ]] ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That test will always pass :)  Use `-s`

Comment: Maybe you could issue `find` first and use a condition to check if the output file isn't empty.

Comment: `find` returns 0 when all files are successfully processed, even if there are no matches, so you can't just check `$?`

Comment: I suggest this awesome hack: `if find .. | grep "" > file`

Comment: `wc -l file` outputs `0 file`, not just `0`. For this approach, you could go with `[[ -s`, which checks for non-empty file and avoids counting lines at all.

Comment: @thatotherguy the `grep` hack looks good! had a closer look now. Before was just about to fix my untested :) answer..

Comment: You need the `rm /tmp/output.txt` after the `fi` so that it is removed even when it is empty.  Arguably, the name should be decorated with `$$` or created with the `mktemp` command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. Oh man! crazy answer with 1000 bugs.. :) srry for confusion SO community! Are the `$$` in front a convention for temporary files? I would prefer `mktemp` as you've suggested as an alternative because the file's name can't be guessed by other programs / users then.

Comment: More frequently, you use a name like `/tmp/output.$$.txt` with the `$$` near the end.  It is a simple technique to make sure that concurrent runs of the script don't try using the same file at the same time (because each has its own value for `$$`, of course).  It is not a security measure – the name can be guessed.  Using `mktemp` gives a filename that is randomly generated from a template but is unique, which makes it much harder for an attacker to guess the name that a process will use for its temporary file.  It provides a measure of security which using `$$` certainly doesn't.